# Can you explain Rails 5 Models, Controllers, and Helper Methods usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to follow the guideline:

> **Skinny Controller; Fat Model**

How does one call a method defined in a Model when they want to use it in a controller? What is a **"Helper Method"** and a **"Module"** and how are those used to pass methods around?

Let's say I have a Model, Controller, and View for a `Car`,

---

#### models/car.rb

```
# == Schema Information ==
#
#  Table name: cars
#
#  id             :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#  make           :string(255)
#  model          :string(255)
#  year           :integer(4)
#
class Car < ApplicationRecord

end
```

---

#### controllers/cars_controller.rb

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

---

#### views/show.html.erb

```
<h1>My Car</h1>
<p>
  My car is a <%= @car.description %>.
  <%# Expected output "My car is a 1967 Chevy Impala" %>
</p>
```

If I want my `description` method to be something like:

```
def description
    car.year + ' ' + car.make + ' ' + car.model
end
```

Where do I put this method? I assume not the Controller. If it goes in the Model, how do I call it from the Controller? Also, if I have a Model for `trucks` and `boats` can I use a Helper Method to call my `description` method with those? Would I then need to put the method in a Module? If so, what would you name the Module, where would you save it, and how would you call it in your Model or Controller?

I keep reading that you should keep logic out of the controller and that you should put it in the model and then call it in the controller if needed. I also read that you should put it in a module or a helper method and call it that way. I was hoping someone could explain how to do those things and why you would do one over the other.

Comment: If it goes in the model, why do you need to call it in the controller, and what for? You already call it in the view. (which is also the same way you'd do it in the controller)

Comment: Me personally, I'd either put it in the model or a presenter/decorator (these are patterns you can look up)

Comment: I keep reading things that say "keep the logic out of the controller, put it in the model and call it from there if you need it in the controller" but then I will read another article that says, "use a helper method so you can call it anywhere you need it" I've not found a good explanation of when you should do these things or how to properly use self-defined Helper Methods. I was hoping someone could show me a clear, concise example of how each was done, and maybe, when to do it each way.

Comment: Well, this is enough material for 2-3 book chapters :)

Comment: Skinny *everything*